# shift() method is not running correctly, it only shift for 2-3 times and then it wouldn't shift

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop

Here is my code please give some solutions.

#### Input:-

```
var b = [167,244,377,56,235,269,23];

for(var temp=0;temp<b.length;temp++){

    console.log(b)
    b.shift();
}
```

#### output:-

```
[ 167, 244, 377,56, 235, 269,23]
[ 244, 377, 56, 235, 269, 23 ]
[ 377, 56, 235, 269, 23 ]
[ 56, 235, 269, 23 ]
```

Comment: If `b` shrinks, then `b.length` gets smaller too, so `temp<b.length` happens sooner.

Comment: You need to use `while`

Comment: `while(b.length){}`

Answer (score 3):

`Condition` in for-loop is checked everytime. And every time `b.lenght` is smaller and smaller.
You just need to save `b.length` somewhere and use its value.

```
var b = [167,244,377,56,235,269,23];
const length = b.length;

for(var temp=0;temp<length;temp++){
    console.log(b)
    b.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you shift you remove an items from the array. The array size shrinks. You are looping over the current array length, not the original array length.

```
i=0; b.length=7 --> 0 < 7 === true
i=1; b.length=6 --> 1 < 6 === true
i=2; b.length=5 --> 2 < 5 === true
i=3; b.length=4 --> 3 < 4 === true
i=4; b.length=3 --> 4 < 3 === false
```

So either you store the original length, you loop from length to zero, or use a while loop.

```
var b = [...]
var length = b.length;
for(var temp=0; temp<b.length; temp++){
  //code
}
```

or

```
var b = [...]
for(var temp=b.length; temp>=0; temp--){
  //code
}
```

or

```
while(b.length) {
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I order to continue looping until `b` has no elements, remove the `temp++` final expression.

```js
var b = [167, 244, 377, 56, 235, 269, 23];
for (var temp = 0; temp < b.length;) {
  console.log(b);
  b.shift();
}
```

---

Instead, you could move the `shift` method call to the final expression

```js
var b = [167, 244, 377, 56, 235, 269, 23];
for (var temp = 0; temp < b.length; b.shift()) {
  console.log(b);
}
```

---

Since we are removing elements from the array in the [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, we should not increment `temp` at all. With that in mind, we can also convert the loop into a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop.

```js
var b = [167, 244, 377, 56, 235, 269, 23];
while (b.length > 0) {
  console.log(b);
  b.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that happens because when the array is being shifted its length is being incremented too that can be cured by making a constant which has the length of the array firstly here is the code:

```js
var b = [167,244,377,56,235,269,23];
const length = b.length;
for(var temp=0;temp<length;temp++){
    console.log(b)
    b.shift();
}
```